# Can I create Windows-style alias in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, alias

In Windows, we can hold down Ctrl or use right mouse button while dragging the file in Explorer. When we release mouse button we see a menu where we can choose 'Create shortcut'.

It's quite handy, I think. Can we do something similar in Mac OS?

**UPDATE:** I **do** know how to create aliases, I'm interesting whether I can automatically create alias for the folder by just holding some key while dragging or smth like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click any file or folder, press and hold down the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> keys, and then drag the file or folder while continuing to hold down the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> keys.

An alias appears where you release the mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

In Mac OSX you Control+Click (or use the right mouse button) on the file and choose the menu item "Make Alias" then you can place the created Alias wherever you want. This is the same as your shortcut in Windows.

Comment: I know this. I were actually asking whether I can automatically create alias for the folder by just holding some key while dragging or smth like that. It could be much more efficient than constantly clicking right mouse button then 'create alias'