# Moving 'Sites' folder to Dropbox

Tags: snow-leopard, dropbox, webserver

I'm trying to move my standard ~/Sites folder, or the global Sites folder (in Library/WebServer/Documents) to my Dropbox folder, and make this usable with Web Sharing, PHP, MySQL etc.

So far I have changed the httpd.conf in etc/apache2 to overwrite these lines:

```
# original: DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/users/cannyboy/Dropbox/Sites"
# original: <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
<Directory "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/users/cannyboy/Dropbox/Sites">
```

But when I browse http://localhost I get:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just move the Sites folder into the Dropbox folder - and then make a link/alias from the new Dropbox location back to ~/Sites.

After you've moved the Sites folder into Dropbox you right click on the Sites folder in Dropbox, and then choose "Make Alias" and move this alias into ~/ *(remember to rename it to Sites)* - alternativ create the alias this way: [Can I create Windows-style alias in Finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14594/can-i-create-window-style-alias-in-finder/14600#14600)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know default mod for `Dropbox` folder, but `Sites` have read access for anyone (such as apache web server) :

```
ls -Alh ~/

drwx------+ 26 Bil   staff   884B 25 jui 12:40 Desktop
drwx---rwx  22 Bil   staff   748B 24 jui 19:01 Documents
drwx------+ 11 Bil   staff   374B 24 jui 16:47 Downloads
drwx------  49 Bil   staff   1,6K 21 jui 10:07 Library
drwx------+  5 Bil   staff   170B 11 aoû  2010 Movies
drwx------+  5 Bil   staff   170B 26 avr 16:37 Music
drwx------   8 Bil   staff   272B 26 avr 10:35 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x   6 Bil   staff   204B  9 déc  2009 Public
drwxr-xr-x+ 17 Bil   staff   578B 23 jui 14:23 Sites
```

To change access of `Dropbox`, type in `Terminal.app`

```
chmod a+r ~/Dropbox
```

But be careful, once you've change directory's mod, everybody can read view/read it's content.